# Different migration scenarios for different datasources

Tags: java, spring, flyway

Friends, how can I configure the migration of multiple databases using Flyway? In my Spring application, I use 2 databases, the first database (PostgreSQL) is responsible for the web, it stores data of users, roles, etc., and the second database (MySQL) is responsible for business logic. The databases are located on different hosts and are not connected to each other in any way. And of course my datasources have a different data structure.

I have configured two data sources, these are LocalDBConfig and JiraDBConfig.

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource( { "classpath:application.properties" } )
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "net.komus.oksitreport.repo.local",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "localEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "localTransactionManager"
)
public class LocalDBConfig {
    
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "spring.datasource" )
    @FlywayDataSource
    public DataSource customerDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "localEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManager() {
        ...
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager localTransactionManager() {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource( { "classpath:application.properties" } )
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "net.komus.oksitreport.repo.jira",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "jiraEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "jiraTransactionManager"
)
public class JiraDBConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "db.jira.datasource" )
    @FlywayDataSource
    public DataSource jiraDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "jiraEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean jiraEntityManager() {
        ...
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager jiraTransactionManager() {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

I have arranged the migration files by paths:
[image]

The `db/migrate/manager` path should be responsible for Local DB Config migrations, and the `db/migrate/jira` path should be responsible for JiraDBConfig migrations.
I don't understand how to configure the functionality I need.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are nearly there. As far as I can tell there is no out of the box way of having flyway handle two database migrations at the same time. That being said, there is a way to do this with a bit of manual configuration. So, based on your requirements consider the following example:

```
@Configuration
public class PostgresDbConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "postgresDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "primary.datasource")
    @FlywayDataSource
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

And

```
@Configuration
public class MariaDbConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "mariaDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

For our use case these are going to be the two databases (and subsequent datasources) that we are going to be migrating. As you case see my `postgresDatasource` is marked as `@Primary`.

For the primary datasource, we will be letting Flyway doing its own thing, hence the only configuration needed to be put in place is the following:

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/postgresql
```

For the secondary datasource (`mariaDatasource`) what you need to do is to create a Flyway bean that will manually migrate the database. For example consider the following:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfig {

    private final DataSource mariaDatasource;

    public FlywayConfig(@Qualifier("mariaDatasource") DataSource mariaDatasource) {
        this.mariaDatasource = mariaDatasource;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void runMigration() {
        Flyway.configure()
            .dataSource(mariaDatasource)
            .locations("db/migration/mariadb")
            .baselineOnMigrate(true)
            .load()
            .migrate();
    }

}
```

As you can see, this class is being injected with the secondary datasource which is used to create a `Flyway` object manually. It then uses the object in question to perform the migration manually.